# ROI image J automation

Tags: javascript, imagej

I NEED SOME HELP. I AM ALSO NEW TO IMAGE J. 
I have multiple RMI CT Scans, each which has roughly 16 slices, i need to automate a method that will allow the user to,
1) upload any CT Scan from a directory, 
2)identify the middle slice(as this is the only slice from the 16 stack i am interested in) 
3)then select all ROI (circular inserts) in that one slice and calculate the mean and stdDev 
4)and save the image results as the same title used to upload the CT scan.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what did you do?

Comment: Hi, I've currently tried using image J macro,

Comment: Hi, I've currently tried using image J macro, I've been able to select the CT scan and select the roi for one slice, but what i found  was that different CT scans  have the phantom positioned differently so no to scan align perfectly,so my ROI template does not sit within the circular regions when uploading different CT scan.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Plugins -> Macros -> Record in ImageJ.

2) Manually do what you would like to automate.

3) Press "Create" button in the Recorder window to create a new Macros.

Now you can run these **specific** actions.

4) Modify this created Macro file so as to generalize the actions.

I'm sure if you play with this a bit, you will get it :)

Best of luck!